# Password Changes Not Persisting After Shutdown or Logoff

Tags: raspbian, boot, ssh, security, password

If I change the password of user pi (rpi 3b, NOOBS, Raspbian Jessie), it takes affect only until shutting down or logging off. After shutting down or logging off, the new password is no longer current.

I was using SSH and VNC for a couple hours before failing to be able to connect any longer. When I was local again, I was able to change the password and get VNC working again, but only until the next reboot or login.

What would cause this problem?

Comment: Is it possible to name user to rpi 3b, Raspbian Jessie? According to me it is not possible. Since Linux do not allows you to name a directory with a white space(Actually every user is a directory under home directory).

Comment: The stuff in brackets was just context, not part of the user name.

Answer (score 1):

It was malware, due to me creating a vulnerability (SSH, lax pi password). I found  the offending lines in rc.local and elsewhere. I expect the safest option to clean up will be re-imaging my rpi's SD card.

Comment: Definitely re-install from a clean image. Lessons learned! Always secure your system before connecting to the outside.